Topological property that makes it possible for an embedding not to have a continuous left inverse
I was trying to solve the following exercise :

a) If f is a continuous function and f admits a continuous left inverse, it is a topological embedding.


b) Give an example of a topological embedding with no continuous left inverse

My question is about b). I think I have found the following counterexample:
Let $f: (0,1)\rightarrow \mathcal{S}^1$ where $f(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$. Then f is a topological embedding (it is an injective, continuous function that is an homeomorphism onto its image).
I think I was able to show that there is no continuous function $g:\mathcal{S}^1 \rightarrow (0,1)$ such that for all $x \in (0,1), g(f(x)) = x$ by noting first that $g$ must satisfy : $g(e^{2\pi i x}) = x$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and then by showing that, no matter the value of $g$ at $e^{2\pi i \times 0} = e^{2\pi i \times 1} = 1$, $g$ cannot be continuous.
However, looking at the big picture, I am not sure what "allows" such a counterexample to be constructed in the first place. My guess is that there must be some fundamental topological property that makes $\mathcal{S}^1$ and $(0,1)$ different, probably that $\mathcal{S}^1$ is compact, while $(0,1)$ isn't, but I have no idea how this compactness (or another property) is related to the existence of such counterexamples.
So here is my question : What is "allowing" the existence of topological embeddings with no continuous left inverse?
Edit:
As suggested by @Ben Steffan in a comment, the following question can probably be more meaningfully answered:
Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a topological embedding, are there any properties on X and Y that guarantee/prevent the existence of a left inverse (a retraction) for $f$?

Having a left inverse (a retraction) is an exceptional property, not vice-versa. You might be better off asking the opposite question.

This is an open-ended question, so I'll just advocate for a different perspective: There is, rather than any particular something "allowing" this, simply nothing "disallowing" this. The existence of a continuous left-inverse, i.e. a retraction, is a pretty rigid topological property compared to topological embeddings, which abound. E.g. any subspace inclusion $A\subseteq B$  is a topological embedding, but the existence of a retraction $r\colon B\rightarrow A$ implies a much stronger relationship. For starters, if $B$ is Hausdorff, then any retract of $B$ has to be a closed subspace (this recovers your open embedding as a counter-example). There are also more sophisticated implications, e.g. the homology of $A$ splits off as a direct summand of the homology of $B$. The (non-)existence of retractions has been studied a lot historically using such methods, a classical example being the famous fact (equivalent to the Brouwer fixed-point theorem) that the inclusion $S^{n-1}\hookrightarrow D^n,\,n\ge1$ of the boundary sphere of a disk does not admit a retraction.

Thank you for your answer. Coincidentally, before coming up with the counterexample in the main post, I was looking at the inclusion $f: \mathcal{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ (which is for this purpose basically the same as $S^{1}\hookrightarrow D^2$) and was quite convinced that it was also a counterexample, but had no idea how to prove it (at least not yet) and thought I should look for an easier counterexample first.
